# Oracle database query history

Tags: sql, oracle

I already run some queries on oracle database  but next day I want to find this history I tried the mention tables v$sqltext but not found the queries i run ,Also I try to test it by doing a query  "select * from cat"  but I couldn't find this history .

Comment: Look in v$sqlarea

Comment: Look at LRU mechanism from this link : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/memory.htm#i11734

Comment: `v$sqltext` is a dynamic view, basically intended to help the diagnosis of **current**  performance issues. If you want a historical record you should have implemented a proper audit trail. I know that's no help right now but you'll know better next time ;)

Comment: v$sqlstats will generally hold information slightly longer than v$sql, v$sqlarea and v$sqltext, and is much less risky to your system to query this view than the others.  But as already pointed out, it is a temporary store.